# Is there an optimization problem that is NP-Complete?

Tags: algorithm, computation-theory, np, np-complete, np-hard

Is there such a thing as an NP-complete **optimization** (not **decision**) problem?

What is an example of an NP-complete optimization problem?

The decision versions of optimization problems are the ones in NP-complete.
I can't think of any NP-hard optimizations that can be confirmed in polynomial time. I need verification/correction on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Formally, no -- NP-completeness implies membership in NP, and NP formally contains only decision problems. Calling optimization problems "NP-hard" is a minor abuse of terminology.

Comment: There is a class called NP-equivalent problems which is a class of problems that are both NP-hard and NP-easy (i.e. there is a poly time reduction both from and to some NP-complete problem). Note an optimization problem can be reduced from and/or to a decision problem so there's no problem with optimisation problems being NP-equivalent.